# Divs move when resizing page

Tags: css, html

This question has actually been asked a lot of times, but none of the responses that I found worked for me. Maybe I am doing it wrong.
Anyway, I made a site using CSS divs and foolishly used a browser window to make sure everything was aligned correctly. When I was done and I zoomed out, all of the images and other div elements shifted and moved around instead of being fixed like expected.
I vaguely know that the problem has to do with the lack of a wrapper div and/or the fact I used relative and absolute positioning a LOT, just to get it to work.
Any help is appreciated, I am new to CSS and this is my first site I've made with it.
Thanks!
-Zac

**Here is a link the broken site as requested:** http://wctadm.org/

Can't embed screenshot, here is a link: http://imgur.com/MmmGceb
Shows correct alignment as I saw it on one monitor, and the zoomed-out, messed up version.

HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>

</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Default Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
<!-- Content //--->
</div>

<div id="header">
<!-- NAVBAR     <img src="DM-logo.png" alt="DM Logo" height="81" width="130">  //--->

<ul id="menu" style="position: relative; z-index: 100;">
  <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Teachers</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Mrs. Rosarita Olvina</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Mrs. Christine Pavesich</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Mr. Francisco Virella</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Courses</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Photography</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Video Production</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Animation</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Art</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">About</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">What We Do</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Where We Go</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
</ul>


<ul id="logo">
<ul>
<li><img src="dm-button.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -120px; z-index: 1;" height="120" width="120"/></li>
</ul>

<ul id="welcome"> 
<ul>
<li><p style="position: absolute; top: 140px; left: 75px; z-index: 2;">Welcome to Digital Media at WCTA</p></li>
</ul>

<ul id="banner">
<ul>
<li><img src="bannerbackgroundDMwithshadow.png" style="position: absolute; top: 81px; left: -120px; z-index: 0;" height="400" width="859"/></li>
</ul>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>

<div id="quicklinks">
    <div id="links1">
        <img src="courses-icon2.png" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 40px; z-index: 100;" height="97.75" width="139"/>
        <p style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: -10px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;">Explore courses</p>
        <p style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: -30px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; font-size: 12px;">Our courses teach advanced digital media in a wide range of subjects.</p>
        <a href="courses.html" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="more.png" style="position: relative; top: -24px; left: 60px; z-index: 101;" height="33.6" width="98.5"/></a>
    </div>

    <div id="links2">
        <img src="gallery-icon.png" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 40px; z-index: 100;" height="97.75" width="139"/>
        <p style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: -10px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;">View the gallery</p>
        <p style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: -30px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; font-size: 12px;">Gallery of our student's finest work in a variety of mediums.</p>
        <a href="gallery.html" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="more.png" style="position: relative; top: -24px; left: 60px; z-index: 101;" height="33.6" width="98.5"/></a>
    </div>

    <div id="links3">
        <img src="contact-icon2.png" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 40px; z-index: 100;" height="97.75" width="139"/>
        <p style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: -10px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;">Contact us</p>
        <p style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: -30px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; font-size: 12px;">Drop us a line if you have any questions or concerns regarding our program.</p>
        <a href="contact.html" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="more.png" style="position: relative; top: -24px; left: 60px; z-index: 101;" height="33.6" width="98.5"/></a>
    </div>
</div>



<!---------- BLURB //------------------->
<div id="blurb">
    <div id="blurbpic">
        <img src="placeholder.png" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100;" height="250px" width="250px"/>
    </div>

    <div id="blurbtext">
        <p style="text-align: left; position: relative; top: -10px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; font-size: 50px; color:white; font-family:'Open Sans Condensed', sans serif;">Dedicated to excellence</p>
        <p style="text-align: left; position: relative; top: -50px; left: 10px; z-index: 99; font-size: 14px; color:white;">Members of WCTA's Digital Media program are expected to work hard, strive high, and have fun while doing it. With courses in areas ranging from Digital Media to Photography, joining the Digital media program is the best choice you could make to start the journey of your career in technology. Digital Media students not only get access to multiple computer labs and software, but they also get to go out in the field regularly to gain real life experience. </p>
    </div>
</div>

<!---------- FOOTER //------------------->   
<div id="footer">

<ul id="footerpic">
<ul>
<li><img src="footerbackground.png" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: -194px; z-index: 150;" height="173px" width="859px"/></li>
</ul>    

<ul id="footerlogo">
<ul>
<li><img src="DM-logowhite.png" style="position: relative; top: 80px; left: 270px; z-index: 151;" height="58.5" width="88.3"/></li>
</ul>

<ul id="footertext1">
<ul>
<li><p style="position: relative; top: 10px; left: 89px; z-index: 151; font-size: 12px; color:white;">©2013 Zac Clark - Digital Media</p></li>
</ul>       
</div> 

<ul id="footertext2">
<ul>
<li><p style="position: relative; top: -30px; left: 720px; z-index: 151; font-size: 12px; color:white;">About • Contact • FAQ • Find Us</p></li>
</ul>       
</div> 



</div> <!-- Wrapper Div //-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Zac Clark - 2013 */


/* --- Primary Content boxes --*/
body {
background: #F7F7F7;
font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
color: #000000;
font-size: 12px;
/* margin: 0px; */
}

div#container {
width: 859px;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #FFFFFF;
padding: 0px;
}

div#content {
width: 859px;
padding-top: 473px;
background: black;
float: left;
}

div#header {
margin-left:0px; /* 161px */
margin-right:0px;
width: 859px;
height: 481px;
background: #757575;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
float: left;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:859px;
}
/*  --- Quick Links ---  */

div#quicklinks {
width: 859px;
margin: 0px auto;
background: white;
top: 286.3px;
height: 286.3px;
}
div#links1 {
width: 286.3px;
float: left;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #F5F5F5;
height: 286.3px;
padding: 30px;

box-sizing: border-box;
ms-box-sizing: border-box;
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
moz-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 286.3px;
}
div#links2 {
width: 286.3px;
float: left;
margin: 0px auto;
background: white;
height: 286.3px;
padding: 30px;

box-sizing: border-box;
ms-box-sizing: border-box;
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
moz-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 286.3px;
}
div#links3 {
width: 286.3px;
float: right;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #F5F5F5;
height: 286.3px;
padding: 30px;

box-sizing: border-box;
ms-box-sizing: border-box;
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
moz-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 286.3px;
}

/* --- Blurb & Image --- */

div#blurb {
width: 859px;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #333333;
top: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
div#blurbpic {
width: 300px;
float: left;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #333333;
height: 300px;
padding: 30px;

box-sizing: border-box;
ms-box-sizing: border-box;
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
moz-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 300px;
}
div#blurbtext {
width: 559px;
float: right;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #333333;
height: 300px;
padding: 10px;

box-sizing: border-box;
ms-box-sizing: border-box;
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
moz-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 559px;
}

/* --- Clearfix (Ignore) --- */
.clearfix:after {content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden;}
.clearfix {display:inline-block;}
/* Hide from IE Mac \*/
.clearfix {display:block;}



/* --- General Elements --*/
#logo ul li { display: inline; }
#banner ul li { display: inline; }
#welcome ul li { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: transparent;
  margin-left: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#footerlogo ul li { display: inline; }
#footerpic ul li { display: inline; }
#footertext1 ul li { display: inline; }
#footertext2 ul li { display: inline; }

/* --- NAVBAR --- */
ul {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Times;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
li ul { display: none; }
ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 7px solid #CC4D4D;
  padding: 25px 30px 30px 30px;
  background: #333333;
  margin-left: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover { background: #757575; }
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #757575; }
li:hover li a:hover { background: #757575; }

<!---------- FOOTER ------------//>

div#footer {
margin-left:0px; /* 161px */
margin-right:0px;
width: 859px;
height: 173px;
background: #757575;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I think you should tag this question with keywords like html, css. And also upload it to js fiddle for a demo

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of what it should look like?

Comment: That is waaay too much to wade through, but I'd start by getting rid of the transitional doctype and going for one of the strict ones.  (Either HTML 4.01 strict or HTML 5.)  There are many, many rendering differences between strict and standard mode.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the live page?

Comment: How your expected page look like? Please provide a screenshot

Comment: @Leo I posted a screenshot comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
style="position: relative;overflow:auto;"
```

Comment: Why should he do that? And on which elements?

Comment: all of your div css includes that

Comment: That keeps some things fixed, but the format is still messed up and other things still move around.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the absolute positioning on your footer.

```
div#footer {
    width: 859px;
    height: 173px;
    background: #757575;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Looks like you've also got some inline styles on the `<img>` you're using as a background. I don't think it's pushing it where you want it. You need to allow the container to center your footer element.

```
<img src="footerbackground.png" height="173px" width="859px"/>
```

Remove the inline style on that tag and try to avoid them entirely.

Comment: Okay, I got rid of the absolute positioning and inline styles. My footer is now right-aligned. Is that because my container isn't proper?

Comment: Did you try the css above? If you didn't, try adding `margin: 0 auto;` to your `div#footer` and see if that does it.

Comment: Basically, `margin: 0 auto;` is your vertical centering best friend. As long as your element has a width, and it's parent has a larger width, your element will center horizontally. But when elements have `position: absolute;` and are being manipulated by `top:,right:,bottom:,left:`, their margins are ignored and the element is no longer centered. This was happening with the inline styles where your element was absolutely positioned and shoved way up and to the left for some reason.

Comment: Almost 5 years ago I said, "Basically, `margin: 0 auto;` is your vertical centering best friend." Oops, I meant horizontal centering. It is too old to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I waded through your code and got some stuff fixed, but there's a long way to go..

## Some Stuff Fixed

First, of all, delete

```
<!---------- FOOTER ------------//>

div#footer {
margin-left:0px; /* 161px */
margin-right:0px;
width: 859px;
height: 173px;
background: #757575;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}
```

You're not using it, so no need to keep it around and that html comment does weird things to my syntax highlighting.

Next, find the closing `</div>` tag right before `<div id="quicklinks">`, then delete it.
Put a closing `</div>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag..
Why?? Because that `</div>` closes your `container` div.. the one you want everything to be contained in..

Then find

```
<li><img height="173px" src="footerbackground.png" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: -194px; z-index: 150;" width="859px"></li>
```

and delete `position: relative;` .

At this point, your main footer image should be in the proper place.

## A long way to go..

The problem now is positioning the rest of the images and texts inside of this image. For starters, you'll want to get rid of the `position: relative;`s..

Here are my recommendations:

- Don't use inline styles (e.g. `style="as: df;"`). It makes it way too hard to keep track of things and becomes super messy.
- Don't unnecessarily use the `<ul>`s and `<li>`s. Just because you use them for your menu doesn't mean you should use them for everything. Your menu is actually a nested list if you think about it. These random images are not.
- Instead of using an `<img>` element for the image, make it the background of a div; that way you can easily position things inside of it as you would any div.
- Use something like photoshop to combine the DM-logowhite.png and footerbackground.png into a single image. It'll save you a lot of pain and pixel-pushing. And it'll make the next step the last step..
- Put the paragraphs into divs inside the div with the footer image as a background. Float one left, and float the other right. Voila, you're done :)

Obviously I can't do all this for you, but try out my recommendations and let me know how it works out for you or if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I did what you suggested and everything is fixed instead of moving. I do have some more problems now. Firstly, my background-images aren't showing. I also don't know how to manipulate anything now that I can't use the top: and right: attributes. Lastly, if I change my drop-down menu to Absolute, it breaks. It will only work with relative... What should I do? Thanks so much again.